# word wrap pros/cons

Tags: word-wrap

I got used so much to this in notepad++ that when i switched to eclipse/aptana i missed it sooo much. But after some time i did get used to not having that functionality. I guess that it's better not to have it because it is forcing you to watch for "readability" part of coding.

What i want to know is some simple pros/cons about this from more experienced users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I avoid word wrap for code as it makes difficult (at least for me) to read/follow the code and may confuse the person reading code. I feel keeping code within 80 columns is the better approach than using word wrap.